# INSERT INTO .db does nothing. Why is it not working?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sql-insert

```
import sqlite3
fme = open("bestFME.txt", "r")
ln = open("numberline.txt", "r")
lines = fme.readlines()
nums = ln.readlines()
numbers = []

for i in nums:
    numbers.append(int(i[0:-1]))
db = sqlite3.connect("FME111.db")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mn(word TEXT, meaning TEXT)")
a = ""
b = ""
for i in range(0, len(numbers)-1):
        a = ""
        b = ""
        a += lines[numbers[i]+1]
        for k in range(numbers[i]+2, numbers[i+1]):
            b += lines[k]
            db.execute("INSERT INTO mn(word, meaning) VALUES(?, ?)", (a, b))

db.close()
```

Comment: Doesn't the python sqlite binding require an explicit commit? Double check the documentation.

Comment: Also, please fix your code formatting so it's readable.

Comment: @Shawn I already did that for him.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need a `cursor` and `commit` the changes once you insert.
Try as said below.

```
db = sqlite3.connect("FME111.db")

#Get the cursor
dbcursor = conn.cursor()

#execute with cursor
dbcursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mn(word TEXT, meaning TEXT)")
a = ""
b = ""
for i in range(0, len(numbers)-1):
        a = ""
        b = ""
        a += lines[numbers[i]+1]
        for k in range(numbers[i]+2, numbers[i+1]):
            b += lines[k]
            #execute with cursor
            dbcursor.execute("INSERT INTO mn(word, meaning) VALUES(?, ?)", (a, b))

#Commit with connection
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir

Answer (score 0):

You may need a cursor. Below is a working code

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("school.db")
curr = conn.cursor()

curr.execute('''INSERT INTO student VALUES (?,?,?,?)''', (name, lname, fac, school))
```